# How to share my blog on facebook

Tags: facebook

I would like to be able to share my blog on my facebook profile but my blog's domain ends with ".dx.am". These are the ones offered by awardspace. Facebook says "The content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe". That's because of the domain. So anyway to overcome this?

Comment: I think facebook does not allowed that kind of domain you should use example.com/sample

Comment: If the dx.am URL has been blocked, you can submit an appeal here: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/571927962827151